# Android Studio - gradle warning: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I got the warning at the below line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

The warning:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification 
(mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). 
Found versions 28.0.0, 24.0.0. 
Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 
and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, 
that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. 
One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of 
the Android support libraries that is not the latest version 
(or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  
Issue id: GradleCompatible
```

Below is my build.gradle(app) code (New update for Firebase Libraries)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vanessa.orderfoodserver"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //Add Library
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

    //Received the warning at below line
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0' //ForLocation
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried to add

```
com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0
com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0
com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0
```

but still the warning still exists.

I can run my app but I still want to fix this warning. Thanks!

Comment: it one of the library that you have added is using older version, you need to update it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Comment: @KaranMer Hi, I have checked the Google's Maven Repository: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html, and update all of my libraries to the latest version, but the warning still exists

Comment: check for the third party libraries they might be causing this, try using their latest version.

Comment: you can also try excluding support package from this libraries by excluding them, add this after you define your dependency. `{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}`

Comment: @KaranMer Hi, could you specify where to add this line, I've added it at the end of dependencies (inside the bracket), but error pops up.

Comment: first try and comment the each dependency individually that will help you identify which one is causing this error, you can then add this at end of that particular dependency.

Comment: @KaranMer hi, I updated all third party libraries and still doesn't work, I will try commenting each dependency, thanks!

Comment: looks like you are using older versions of firebase libraries, one of them might be using the older support library, try upgrading them first

Comment: @KaranMer oh sorry I forgot to update firebase libraries, but I still get the warning after update, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.1.0'
```

or try

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code, the warning still exists, and a new warning appears on the implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0' line

Comment: Hi, I tried the updated one but the same warning still exists.

Comment: whats is ur buildtoolversion? add this  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

Comment: My Android Gradle Plugin is 3.3.0, I tried buildToolsVersion '28.0.3', still not work

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is, try look into every latest version of every individual library for your project. Some of the library not even same version to each others. Lib A ver might be 2.0 and Lib B ver might be 2.5, but both is the latest (example such as Firebase). This dependency library version is part of the Android Studio 3.0.+ migration.